# Ethernet internet randomly loses internet access 18.04

Tags: network-manager, internet, ethernet

Ubuntu 18.04. 90% of the time, my internet is fine. But occasionally, my ethernet loses access to the internet. After about 5 minutes it usually regains access, or after I log out of the user sessions and back in.

Not a network issue bc my phone still has internet access.

What info do I need to share with you guys to assist in helping me?

```
 lcpci
```

yields this for my ethernet:

```
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)
```

results from pinging 8.8.8.8 https://pastebin.com/zwdbLmHe

Comment: Try a different network cable. On my network, newly-failed cables turn out to be the problem about half the time for intermittent network failures. Sometimes they worked flawlessly for years first.

Comment: `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`, and `sudo journalctl --since="-10 minutes"` will show interesting log messages.